# SSIS Package failing, not redirecting error rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

We have an SSIS package to import data from CSV flat file to a table on SQL Server. The file consists of several hundred lines of data that are delimited by a comma(,) with text data qualified by double quotes ("), but not all the text columns are qualified by double quotes.  The problem arises when a string that is not qualified by quotes (") contains comma (,). This cause the package to fail with following error

> [Source Data [130]] Error: The column delimiter for column "ColumnX" was not found.

I tried to redirect the bad rows to another flat file destination, but the package is not redirecting the bad rows, but its failing

Comment: SSIS won't be able to redirect the row because the row is malformed. If you have a value that *isn't* quote identified and does contain a comma then to any CSV reader it's going to look like that row has an extra column. The problem isn't SSIS it's your file, and you need to fix it so that values that do contain commas are properly quoted.

Comment: @Larnu: Yes I manually removed the comma and processed the file, but its not an ideal fix for daily process.

Comment: It's not about a manual fix, the upstream systems generating this file should apply this fix

Comment: As @RaunakJhawar said, it shouldn't be you manually fixing the file, you (or whomever is responsible) should be fixing the process that creates the file. The fault is at the file generation, not the import, as the file that is trying to be imported is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get whoever generates the file to fix it, your only programmatic solution is to write a script task that fixes the file before it goes to the dataflow.

The script would need to analyze each row to see if it has the right number of commas, and to add quotation marks around the fields.   If it finds one with too many commas, it would have to apply some logic (which only you can determine) to decide which comma isn't a column delimiter and make sure that comma is either deleted or enclosed in the quoted field value.